# How to get https for nodejs launched on aws ec2 instance and connected to domain using route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a nodejs app and hosted it on aws ec2.

Enabled HTTPS, HTTP in the security. I purchased a domain from an external domain provider and connected nameservers using route53.

Now, when I am opening the domain it showing not secure. How Can I make it secure. I tried listen port in 443 but then domain was not opening.
Can Someone please help how to make it secure or provide some good documentation for begineers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use a load balancer to front your instance, then you have to get and install a **third party SSL certificate** on your instance for your domain.

A popular choice are certificates from https://letsencrypt.org/ (StackOverflow uses them as well). They also provide https://certbot.eff.org/ tool for easy installation and setup of the SSL certs on a variety of operating systems and servers.